# Why is el after a collection fetch is undefined

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, requirejs, backbone-views, backbone-events

I have this view (ordersView) that fetch orders on initialization and upon complete re-renders the view. The el attribute is defined on instantiating the said view and so in the router. I call the render after instantiate and shows the #order el, but after fetch el is then undefined, why is this?

[image: console logs notice logs on line 36]

My **ordersView.js** view:

```
// Menu View
// =============

// Includes file dependencies
define([ "jquery",
         'underscore',
         "backbone",
         'handlebars',
         "collections/menu",
         "collections/orders",
         "collections/stores",
         'hbs!template/ordersTemplate',
], function( $, _, Backbone, Handlbars, MenuCollection, OrdersCollection, StoresCollection, OrdersTemplate ) {

    // Extends Backbone.View
    var OrdersView = Backbone.View.extend( {


        // The View Constructor
        initialize: function() {

            OrdersCollection.fetch({'success': this.render})

        },

        events: {
        },        

        showMoreInfo: function(e) {
            $(e.target).closest('.store').toggleClass('hideinfo');
        },

        // Renders all of the Category models on the UI
        render: function() {
            console.log('rendered');
            console.log( this.$el );
            this.$el.html( OrdersCollection.toJSON() );

        }


    } );

    // Returns the View class
    return OrdersView;

} );
```

and here is my **router.js** file:

```
// Filename: router.js
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  '../views/ordersView',
], function($, _, Backbone, OrdersView) {

  var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
      // Default
      '*actions': 'defaultAction'
    }
  });

  var initialize = function(){

    var app_router = new AppRouter;

    app_router.on('route:defaultAction', function (actions) {
        var ordersView = new OrdersView({ el: $("#orders") });
        ordersView.render();
    });

    Backbone.history.start();
  };
  return { 
    initialize: initialize
  };
});
```

I am using JQuery jquery-1.10.2, Backbone.js backbone-amd 1.0.0, and RequireJS AMD loader

Comment: I haven't used backbone, but it looks like a execution context problem, you may have to use _bind() to bind the desired context to `render` function before it is passed to `OrdersCollection.fetch({'success': this.render})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try binding the execution context to `render()` before it is padded to `.fetch()`

ex

```
OrdersCollection.fetch({'success': _.bind(this.render, this)})
```

Comment: great, the el is now persistent, thanks for this, one last question how do I unbind everytime another success fetch?

Comment: @user1076813 it is required to be binded only once